# WCF Between Matlab & a C# application

Tags: c#, wcf, matlab, wsdl

I am trying to communicate between 2 applications.
1 matlab application
1 C# written application.

The C# application publishes its functions with the Microsoft WSDL application that is non-standard and matlab cannot understand it.

Do you know of any solutions to this problem?
Some application that does publish the WCF functions in a standard manner or some automatic tool that fixes this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A well-known issue - actually, the Microsoft output **is** standard-compliant, but most other systems don't support it :-)

Check out these WCF extensions that will allow you to "flatten" your WSDL to include the XSD as inline `<wsdl:schema>` elements:

- [Flatten your WSDL with this Custom ServiceHost for WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/23/flatten-your-wsdl-with-this-custom-servicehost-for-wcf.aspx)
- [Improving WCF Interoperability: Flattening your WSDL](http://blogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/archive/2007/05/10/414840.aspx)
- [Flatten WCF WSDL on demand](http://www.steverb.com/post/2008/11/22/Flatten-WCF-WSDL-on-Demand.aspx)
- [Inline XSD in WSDL for WCF](http://winterdom.com/2006/10/inlinexsdinwsdlwithwcf)

Hope that helps!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

You can change the C# application as a .net remonting service.

And then, you can use matlab-net-api call C# dll to communicate with the service.

As the mode, you can use WCF as a service and use use matlab-net-api call C# dll to communicate with the service.

Answer (score 0):

**IPC:** You can do this with interprocess communication. For example you could use a socket or a named pipe.

**DLL:** Or if you just want to use the C# methods in Matlab you could build a .NET framework dll and use it in matlab with `NET.addAssembly('path to your dll');`

**MQTT:** If the interprocess communication is to complicated, you could also use MQTT for simple messaging (for example JSON) between the processes.